How to Create a 3D Earth Relief Model in Blender?
I'm trying to create a realistic 3D Earth globe with an exagerated and detailed terrain relief (like mountains, valleys, etc.) in Blender, similar to the one in the reference images. The goal is to have the surface show elevation differences, but I'm struggling to make the terrain look smooth rather than overly sharp or pointy. I'm using a topographic displacement map to apply the elevation data.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Applied a Subdivision Surface Modifier to increase geometry.
Used a Displacement node connected to the material, with a PNG topographic map as the texture.
Adjusted the displacement strength, but the terrain still ends up looking too "spiky" in places.
I’m aiming for a softer, more realistic look for the terrain. Then I am aiming to make an animation where the Continents appear slowly. Could anyone recommend techniques or settings to smooth out the displacement or suggest a better approach for achieving a smooth, detailed Earth relief model in Blender?
Thanks in advance!
This is what i have so far

The terrain looks to pounty and pixelated, I want to make it look smoother, like in the image below

This is the Result I am aiming to achieve:

This is how my material displacement setup. I am using a topographic texture from nasa.

Finally here is an effect I want to achieve later, where the continents appear slowly. I want the borders of the continents to connect smoothly with the oceans as they come out


Have you tried adding more subdivisions? Looks to me like you just need more geo

I've tried this, but the terrain becomes too 'pointy.' While it adds more detail, the elevation points are sharp and exaggerated. What I'm aiming for is a smooth, more natural relief, similar to what you can see in the third image.

First of all: what you see in your reference image is not a height map of Earth, as you can see the ridges etc. there do not correspond to real mountains on Earth. This looks more like someone took a bed sheet in the shape of the continents and pulled here and there to get some folds and wrinkles as if there were mountains. But that does not mean you cannot get something smoother from a height map.
What you need is either a smoother map which has less harsh transitions from one pixel to the other, eventually by blurring it in an image editor (but then you lose detail) or you have to manipulate the values a bit. The mountain ranges partly have a lot of peaks with deep valleys, and if you exaggerate the scale then the height difference between peak and valley will be exaggerated too and everything will become a bit pointy, this is nothing you can avoid completely.
However, if you do not need exactly real-world ratios between higher and lower values, you can use a Float Curve node to smoothen out everything by having a curved interpolation instead of linear interpolation. The highest peaks will still be pointy, but less extreme:

To smoothen the borders between oceans and continents more, you probably really have to blur the edges in an image editor. But also your animation of the appearing continents looks very sharp, how did you do it? Simply by scaling the displacement or differently?

Hi Gordon, Thank you for your response. I will try to follow your advice. As for the animation. I used a color ramp between the heightmap and the displacement. Then I tweaked the values of the color ramp to make the continents appear and dissapear
